# Inject parameters in method using custom Data Attribute, is that possible?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I want create some Data Attribute to decorate methods of system that I'm working. I saw that in a lot of points in the system application, developers instantiate an database context based on some information. Something like that:

```
public IQueryable<Customers> ListCustomersByName(Username user, Password password, string firstName)
{
    var context = DatabaseContextFactory(user, password);
    return context.Customers.Where(c => c.FirstName == firstName);
}
```

Look that, in real, my method only need one information to look for customer, that is the customer first name. And a lot of other methods like that exists here.
My idea is do something like that:

```
[UsesDatabaseAttribute]
public IQueryable<Customers> ListCustomersByName(Database context, string firstName)
{
    return context.Customers.Where(c => c.FirstName == firstName);
}
```

Then, I will call my method passing, username, password, and name to search. Something like that:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var customers = ListCustomersByName(username, password, firstName);
    //... Use this list to do anything
}
```

And my DataAttribute will receive that, translate, and call the method passing the context of database.

In short therm, I want remove all the logic of instantiate database from each of those methods, and centralize this into the Attribute that decorates the method.

Trying to exemplify, my idea is have the same of the code bellow, but instead of have method overload, I want decorate method with Data Attribute (because this scenery repeats with other methods and other tables, and I want avoid overload for every different table):

```
public IQueryable<Customers> ListCustomersByName(Username user, Password password, string firstName)
{
     var context = DatabaseContextFactory(user, password);
     return ListCustomersByName(context, firstName);
}

public IQueryable<Customers> ListCustomersByName(Database context, string firstName)
{
    return context.Customers.Where(c => c.FirstName == firstName);
}

public static void Main()
{
    var customers = ListCustomersByName(username, password, firstName);
    //... Use this list to do anything
}
```

Is that or something like that possible?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do. In your second code snippet, did you intend to use `context` somehow?

Comment: Yeah, sure. I edited the code. The code was wrong because I wrote this directly on stack overflow, just to exemplify the idea. Take a look now!

Answer (score 1):

As i understand you want to inject dependency(context) into class that contains method for access database. For this you can use some DI containers, for example try unity https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648211.aspx
code will be look like this:

```
class ContextFactory
{
  public Context Create(string userName, string Password)
  {
  //creating context
  }
}

class SomeClass
{
  private ContextFactory _factory;
  public SomeClass(ContextFactory factory)
  {
    _factory = factory;
  }

  public IQueryable<Customers> ListCustomersByName(Username user, Password password, string firstName)
  {
      var context = _factory.Create(user, password);
      return customers.Where(c => c.FirstName == firstName);
  }
}

public static void Main()
{
  //creating container and register dependency
  var container = new UnityContainer();
  container.RegisterType<ContextFactory>();

  var someClass = container.Resolve<SomeClass>();

  var customers = someClass.ListCustomersByName(username, password, firstName);
    //... Use this list to do anything
}
```

Comment: Yes, the idea is inject dependency. But here we use an close framework that call those methods by reflection. The idea is intercept this call, to get the username and password, create (or get by some factory) the context, and inject that on method.]

Comment: How your framework injects dependency, can it pass it via constructor or properties? If yes, then you can use my code snippet above.

Comment: I really don't know how it injects the dependency (I don't have access to this framework too D=), I only have access to the method being called. And I can create any other methods, and they will be called when something in view happens. That's why I'm trying to "intercept" and change the behavior every time method is called.

Comment: Can you post some existed class in project with some 'intercepter' attribute?

Comment: I didn't understand. I haven't any 'intercepter' attribute, the idea is create something like that (if that is possible)